# Making apk on python with buildozer

Tags: android, python, kivy

I am trying to do apk with buildozer, but I always get this error:

```
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python2.7 build.py --name 'My Application' --version 1.0 --package org.test.mypro --private /home/anar/Документы/kv/.buildozer/android/app --sdk 14 --minsdk 8 --orientation sensor debug
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above
```

I read about this problem, and found advices which say that i should to install 32bit libraries, but it doesnt help me at all, so i don't know what to do:(

Answer (score 0):

If you're on ubuntu or similar, you can probably install the necessary dependencies with the following:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential ccache git zlib1g-dev python2.7 python2.7-dev libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386 openjdk-7-jdk unzip
```

If that doesn't help, post the full log of buildozer, with log_level set to 2 in the buildozer.spec.